# Sending a picture in an inside mailing system, jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

i'm developping my first application, using cordova-phonegapp => jquery/html/css.
There is a mail system inside the application, like, a user can send a message to another user, thanks to the application.
Does someone know if you can/how you put the possibility to add a picture of your phone in a message ? You know, with a camera button, you'd have access to your phone pictures' gallery , choose one, and put it in the message?

Thanks (and sorry for the bad english ...) !